# MySQL IS IN() AS A RESULT

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I display in `SELECT` results `1` if a variable exits in other table and `0` if not? Is it possible or I have to `JOIN`? And in case it is possible only by `JOIN`, what if my `SELECT` is really complicated and I want to `LIMIT` it before `JOINING`?

Lets say that `table 1` and `table 2` contain column named `pid`. Would like to select `*` from `table 1` , limit it to 100 results (`limit 100`), and add one column to results determinating if a `pid` of a result in `table 1` is in `table 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT t1.*, (t2.pid IS NOT NULL) exists_in_table2
  FROM
(
  SELECT *
    FROM table1
   ORDER BY pid
   LIMIT 100
) t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.pid = t2.pid
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f34d/2)** demo

Comment: the problem is more complicated, can we chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41451/fewfaegewa)? I am getting duplicate column error...

Answer (score 0):

Try @peterm solution and if you want to check more conditions you can use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement

```
SELECT t1.*, 
case when t2.pid IS NULL then 0 else 1 end as exists_in_table2
  FROM
(
  SELECT *
    FROM table1
   ORDER BY pid
   LIMIT 100
) t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.pid = t2.pid
```

This is the same as @peterm told, I just changed the checking with CASE statement and the [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f34d/7)